# Odd behaviour when changing rigid body velocity inside OnCollisionEnter2D

Tags: unity, 2d, physics

This is the code I'm using to make an object bounce across the scene:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class Enemy2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _speed;
    
    private Rigidbody2D _rb;

    private Vector2 _velocity;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Vector2 dir = Random.insideUnitCircle;
        if (_rb.velocity.x == 0 && _rb.velocity.y == 0)
            dir = new Vector2(0.5f,0.5f);
        
        _velocity = dir.normalized * _speed;
        _velocity = new Vector2(0, -1);
        _rb.velocity = _velocity;

        FaceDirection();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collision: "+_rb.velocity);
        _velocity = new Vector2(0, +1);//Vector2.Reflect(_velocity, other.contacts[0].normal);
        _rb.velocity = _velocity;
    }

    private void FaceDirection()
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(_velocity.x),1);
    }
}
```

I have hardcoded the initial and Reflect directions just to make sure it wasn't my fault and it produces same behaviour: The object gets stuck when colliders with a collider instead of "rebound".

I'm using a dynamic rigid body with trigger set to false and no linear drag.

Can anybody guess what's hapenning here?

Answer (score 1):

In general you should not set a rigidbody’s velocity directly, as it often results in weird behavior, per the docs:

[Rigidbody2D.velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html)

Instead, try [AddForce()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html), [AddTorque()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddTorque.html) or [AddForceAtPosition()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForceAtPosition.html)

Comment: I tried AddForce before asking, same thing happens.

Comment: @Notbad hmm ok — can you share a minimal version of your scene set up (hierarchy etc?)

Comment: Well, I found the issue. And it is just embarrasing. I think I was tweaking the character in editor and lost all values when exited and forgot to reset the gravity scale to 0. The velocity version works ok. And I think I will stick with it because in my case makes more sense than ApplyForce.

Comment: @Notbad no worries -- often simply asking the question lets you reframe your mindset into seeing the problem through a different lens. Congrats on getting out of this rabbit hole!